# Displaying what `history` line is current in bash prompt

Tags: bash, formatting, command-line, history

What formatting character needs to be added to a `bash` prompt to indicate the most recent `history` item run (or the current command number if 1 could be added to the last `history` entry)?

My prompt string is this:

```
\[\033[33m\][\u@\[\033[1;31m\]\h]\]\033[0m {\W}\n\033[1;34m\]\w\]\033[0m >
```

Gives me the following display:

```
[user@host] {~}
~ >
```

User is in yellow, and the host is in red. The entry in brackets is the current directory, and the entry before the greater-than sign is the full `pwd`.

Can I append to the first line the current command number so I would have something like the following:

```
[user@host] {~} (nnn)
~ >
```

where `(nnn)` is the current (or just processed) command number, as shown when running `history`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [PROMPTING section](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Printing-a-Prompt) of the bash man page:

```
\!     the history number of this command
\#     the command number of this command
```

and further down:

> The command number and the history
>   number are usually different: the
>   history number of a command is its
>   position in the history list, which
>   may include commands restored from the
>   history file ..., while the command
>   number is the position in the sequence
>   of commands executed during the
>   current shell session.

If you want the last command number, you could wrap the number in an arithmetic evaluation like this:

```
export PS1='last cmd num: $((\# -1)), this num: \# '
```